# Import vs Gradle Implementation... which to use when?

Tags: android, gradle, import, build, package

When following an Android tutorial such as [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview), where it is mentions something like, "you will need to use the 'android.support.v4.widget package' in order for this to work," how do you know whether to simply use an import statement in your java code, vs implementing the package in the build.gradle file?  (Other than trying both).

Comment: The dependencies you're declaring inside your Gradle file, just make it possible for you to have the resources in order to import a specific class from your resources.
For example, if you're using GSON inside your project, it's impossible to import it, without it being declared in your Gradle file, or another dependency you're using.

Comment: My question was how do you know whether it's possible or not (without someone having to tell you on stackoverflow for each case).

Comment: if you're not declaring a needed dependency, you'll not be able to build your project as there's no resource to import. Starting a project, you must have a clear sight on which dependencies you're using or wanna use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the class or method you are going to use. If you find some code in a tutorial or like here on StackOverflow, while implementing that code, in case you receive an error like cannot resolve symbol you will have to check for that class on the internet, find the package and related dependency or jar.

In case you are using IDE like AndroidStudio you will get a suggestion for import in case the required class is already available in the added libraries else you will have to check if any dependency needs to be added(Based on class name).